# TableviewCell: set constraints programmatically inside ContentView using autoresize

Tags: swift, uitableview, constraints

I am trying to constraint elements (UIView or UITextfield) in a TableViewCell. If i am using a frame like 
`UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 150, y: 0, width: 500, height: 110))` 
everything works fine.
But i am trying to use autoresize and somehow my UITextfield added as SubView in my Cell don't have the same ancestor. The error message is:
 *"they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?"*

```swift
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var Testtext: UITextField{
            let test = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 150, y: 0, width: 500, height: 110))
            test.textColor = .red
            test.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 22)
            test.text = "Hello World"
            return test
        }


        var cell:UITableViewCell {
            let createdCell = UITableViewCell()
            createdCell.contentView.addSubview(Testtext)
//            Testtext.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
//            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
//                Testtext.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:  createdCell.topAnchor),
//                Testtext.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: createdCell.bottomAnchor),
//                Testtext.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: createdCell.trailingAnchor),
//                Testtext.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: createdCell.leadingAnchor)
//                ])
            return createdCell
        }
```

BTW: I don't want to create a Cellclass, because i need to adjust the number of Textfields and UIViews depending on the input arrayscount.

Comment: You can adjust the number of textfield inside your custom cell class by passing the array count or whatever you need there.

Comment: And how do i pass the array count into a class?

Comment: Just don't make it private and you can call it from your cell instance like this `cell.someVariable = array.count`, same applies to functions.

Comment: don't do it this way, homie, you're in a world of hurt if you follow this path. subclass the cell and use arrays to handle the count of the how many text fields you need.

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
var cell:UITableViewCell {
        let createdCell = UITableViewCell()
        createdCell.contentView.addSubview(Testtext)
       Testtext.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            Testtext.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:  createdCell.contentView.topAnchor),
            Testtext.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: createdCell.contentView.bottomAnchor),
            Testtext.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: createdCell.contentView.trailingAnchor),
            Testtext.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: createdCell.contentView.leadingAnchor)
        ])
        return createdCell
}
```

but this isn't the correct way you need to `dequeueResuableCell` inside `cellForRowAt` to generate the cells instead of creating vars

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CustomCell 
   return cell
}
```